# Could not rollback, connection closed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Recently I have upgrade all my jar files to the latest version (Spring 4.2.x, JPA and Hibernate)

Now I am facing some issues with the test cases. Here is the stackTrace of the test...

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:548)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:853)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:830)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:218)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:93)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:111)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:544)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: rollback failed
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:108)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to rollback against JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:211)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:3948)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doRollback(JdbcTransaction.java:163)
    ... 28 more
```

It says the connection is closed....and cannot rollback. does the pool connection from hibernate auto close the connection? Does anyone have any idea on what is the causing of this?

Edit:
Test code added (the test is big if more information is needed I will edit again)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "testConfig.xml" })
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "test.txManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class ControllerTest {
... logs ... 

    @Autowired
    private Controller controller;
    static final String testIdValue = "114294";
    ... other decorations...

    private Request createRequest() throws Exception {
        Request r = new Request();
        r.setTask(true);
        other set for test values...
        r.assignTaskList(...);
        ...
        return r;
    }

    @Test
    public void assignEndpointsForsSynchTest() throws Exception {

        Request req = createRequest();

        try {
            Response resp = Controller
                    .assignTask(req);
            assertTrue(req.SUCCESSFUL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage());
            fail("Unexpected Exception");
        }
    }

}
```

For the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                    ">

    <bean id="log4jInitialization"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:log4j.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="test.dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        lazy-init="false">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:h2:mem:test_mem;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=ORACLE" />
    </bean>

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="test.dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="com/sky/ac/core/engine/comp/schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="com/sky/ac/core/engine/comp/test_data.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>


    <bean id="test.txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="test.entityMgrFactory" />
        <property name="jpaDialect"> <!-- to support mixed jpaDAO and jdbcTemplateDAO access -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="test.entityMgrFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="paPersistence" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.sky.ac.core.lock.data</value>
                <value>com.sky.ac.core.vs.dao.jpa</value>
                <value>com.sky.ac.core.sr.data</value>
                <value>com.sky.ac.core.rule.data</value>
                <value>com.sky.ac.core.util.data</value>
                <value>com.sky.ac.core.trace.data</value> 
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="test.dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="test.txManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

....bean class defs....
```

Comment: Can you post the test as well?

Comment: let me know if more information is needed to provide. I mean the same code i ran with previous version it works but somehow newer version has errors

Comment: Your `test.entityMgrFactory` bean uses a `jpaVendorAdapter` with database property set to `ORACLE`, and your `dataSource` property points to a H2 dataSource with `ORACLE` mode. Did you try to disable `ORACLE` mode and change `jpaVendorAdapter` to H2? It is only to test what happens.

Comment: switched to mode=MYSQL and value=H2 still the same error. The database type doesn't really matter. it is the issue of hibernate. If i disable entire hibernate it will run if I just use spring / jdbc

Comment: The issue I think is hibernate close the connection after session/transaction and it wasn't returned to the connecton pool so it cannot reuse the connection and cause this.

Comment: You don't need to set the dialect on the transaction manager that is already done for you, remove the `hibernate.connection.release_mode` as I suspect that is the culprit. You also declare your database as `ORACLE` where you are clearly not using ORACLE but H2. (although you do run H2 in ORACLE mode doesn't mean the OracleDialect fully works!).

Comment: @M.Deinum I think you are somewhat right. When I removed '@Transaction' and '@TransactionManager' it works fine. as I see it also call the hibernate without issues. but why?

Comment: Removing that basically removes all transactionallity and leaves it to the testcase however nothing will be issued to the server so no statements will be issued.

Comment: The data still pass through the transaction though, for example I was still able to get the data from dao even if the @transaction was removed. am I missing something?

Comment: Please check answer the answer I posted, accept if solves your problem. Let me know if you continue to have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Please stop using H2 in server mode, use it in embedded mode to
>   support @Transactional rollback.

The above exception is thrown because H2 in server mode not supporting Transaction rollback, it is auto-commit by default. Once your query is executed, it is auto-committed and the session is closed. Hence rollback causes the Exception that is thrown.

To use H2 in embedded mode, add the jar to classpath and replace the datasource bean by `<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />`. In your case the value will be `id="test.dataSource"`.

Here are some known issues in H2 when used in Server Mode:

- [problem with transaction rollback in server mode](http://osdir.com/ml/h2-database/2014-06/msg00181.html)
- [transactions not working with Spring 3.1 – H2 – junit 4– hibernate 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574988/transactions-not-working-with-spring-3-1-h2-junit-4-hibernate-3-2)
- [Using Spring, why can H2 transaction rollback work correctly in embedded-database mode, but not in server mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484180/using-spring-why-can-h2-transaction-rollback-work-correctly-in-embedded-databas)

My recommendation is use a database that well supports transactions with commit and rollback for testing, e.g. [MySQL InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-introduction.html).

Please let me know if you continue to have the Exception even after trying this.

Answer (score 0):

There was a quite similar bug in Spring 3.2.2 RELEASE (Jira [SPR-10395](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10395)) with Hibernate 4.2.

However, you use another Spring version. The issue seems to be in **Hibernate Entity Manager.** (in 4.2.5 Final version at least).

Try to change this Hibernate dependance (upgrade or drowngrade) :

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>4.x.x</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for the response but we do not use maven in our legacy code. it does not apply to this.

Comment: Even if you don't use Maven as software project management (I usually use it), maybe you can test it manually. Actually I'm interested by the root cause (due to Hibernate or something else). Thanks to keep me posted :)

Answer (score 0):

> Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: unexpected error when rollbacking.

it means that there was some disconnection.

To fix issues with disconnection and make jpa able to recconnect to database server, **application.properties** file should contain below properties.

```
spring.datasource.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validation-interval=10000
spring.datasource.log-validation-errors=true
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

Comment: Have attempted this but it wasnt JPA / application properties as other code related to this also uses hibernate for dao and no issues was detected

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are trying to update or insert record and trx is failing due to some reason . By default you have auto-commit on which can cause this issue .
You can try to update below config in application.yaml
datasource:
hikari:
poolName: Hikari
auto-commit: false